# Charts.js displays bars incorrect

Tags: javascript, python, chart.js

[Click to view image. i am trying to make realtime chart. there i got randomly data from django using websocket(its like ajax i guess), but this isnt necessary. bars generated by charts.js is cropped and i dont know why](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkWog.png)

```js
<script>
  var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
  var graphData = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ['Направление Юг-Север', 'Направление Восток-Запад'],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'кол-во машин',
        data: [1, 2],
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(73, 198, 230, 0.5)',
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        // indexAxis: 'y',
    }
  }
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, graphData);
    var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8000/ws/SmartTraffic/')
    socket.onmessage = function(e){
        var djangoData = JSON.parse(e.data);
        console.log(djangoData.yy)
        var newGraphData = graphData.data.datasets[0].data;
        newGraphData.shift()
        newGraphData.push(djangoData.yy);
        graphData.data.datasets[0].data = newGraphData;
        myChart.update();
    }
</script>
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tZY260UyAiE by this tutorial, i made my program. if i remove this line (newGraphData.shift()) bars will be normal(not cropped), but data isnt update, i got static chart.